# How to call a Rails model method in d3.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, d3.js

I'm trying to use d3.js in a simple Rails project. I'm using a very naive way: directly put d3's javascript code inside index.html.erb:

```
#index.html.erb
<script type="text/javascript">
....
rect.on("click", function(d) {
   var dataset = <%= Model.a_method d[0] %>;
....
```

I need to call the method inside the "on click" function, and I'm sure the data(d) has been bind to the "rect" correctly. But inside the `<%= %>`, d is not defined. In other words, if I use something like `<%= Model.a_method 10 %>` instead of using "d", it works fine. Is there a way to overcome this or am I missing something? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The ruby code is on the server side and javascript code is on the client side. You can only first generate javascript code using ruby, and then javascript code can execute. It does not work the other way.
However, you can make REST API and make AJAX call from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is based on MVC pattern, the model is tied with your data and logic, the controller maps HTTP requests to actions to models and present the corresponding view.
(This is a very simple explanation, if you want a more detailed description google will be your best friend).

So what you need to do, is to create an action on your controller that will invoke the method on your model and provide the result to your view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get the idea.